# React , Redux and Firebase storage image fetching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, web, firebase-storage

I am currently fetching images from Firebase storage. I am not sure where to handle the Firebase instantiation eg.

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Also, I am not sure whether these two lines of code are asynchronous

```
 const storage = firebase.storage();

 let gsReference = storage.refFromURL(
 "gs://firebase.appspot.com/image.png");
```

So I should put them into the middleware (I am using redux-thunk, so I carry out asynchronous actions inside my action return dispatch function).

Is there a convention that I should follow regarding these things (ie make a separate Firebase.js file despite me using it only in one location etc. ).

Answer (score 0):

you should probably use a firebase.js where you would initialize firebase and export anything you need from it, in your case

```
//initialize firebase then
export const storage = firebase.storage();
```